# What is complexity of size() for TreeSet portion view in Java

Tags: java, complexity-theory, treeset

I'm wondering what is the time complexity of `size()` for portion view of TreeSet.

Let say I'm adding random numbers to set (and I do not care about duplicities):

```java
    final TreeSet<Integer> tree = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    final Random r = new Random();
    final int N = 1000;
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        tree.add( r.nextInt() );
    }
```

and now I'm wodering what is complexity for `size()` calls as:

```java
    final int M = 100;
    for ( int i = 0; i < M; i++ ) {
        final int f = r.nextInt();
        final int t = r.nextInt();
        System.out.println( tree.headSet( t ).size() );
        System.out.println( tree.tailSet( f ).size() );
        if ( f > t ) {
            System.out.println( tree.subSet( t, f ).size() );
        } else {
            System.out.println( tree.subSet( f, t ).size() );
        }
    }
```

AFAIK complexity of `tree.headSet( t )`, `tree.tailSet( f )` and `tree.subSet( f, t )` are O(lg N), `set.size()` is O(1), but what about `size()` methods above? I have such a bad feeling that it's O(K) where K is size of selected subset.

Maybe if there is some workaround to find index of some element in set it would be enough, because if I can get `ti = indexOf(f)`, in let say O(lg N) than it is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like complexity of `size ()` is `O(N)`, because it may call `TreeMap.NavigableSubMap.EntrySetView.size ()` which is implemented like this (Oracle JDK 1.7.0_13):

```
public int size() {
    if (fromStart && toEnd)
        return m.size();
    if (size == -1 || sizeModCount != m.modCount) {
        sizeModCount = m.modCount;
        size = 0;
        Iterator i = iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            size++;
            i.next();
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify one thing?
Method iterator() will actually return tree's Iterator<> which is O(log N). It will touch only portion of tree by criteria (fromStart()/toEnd()).

As I understood, when headSet() is being created it doesn't actually create a set of elements. It just creates a wrapper with criteria.

Am I wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I returned to that question after some time... You are correct - it creates just a wrapper, but iteration (`while` loop) is still O(K) for subset of size K.